# Fixed Effect Regression - Country-specific time trend

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, plm

I have run a regression on panel data with country fixed effect with `plm` from package `plm`. Breusch-pagan test for time
fixed effects shows that I do not need year fixed effect for my regression. The code for my regression is give below:

```
fe <- plm(
  unemployment ~ fdi + investment + inflation + gdpgrowth + 
    school + trade + naturalresources, 
  data = westa, model = "within"
)
```

However, I want to control for "country-specific time trends." Unfortunately, I am new to R, and I don't know the code required for the country-specific time trend. Which code can I use?

Comment: Country-specific time trend would be then `country_id *year`, both being factor type. Would you be more specific about what you would like to achieve with this?

Comment: I want to capture any other factors which are different across countries and changing over time but I could not control for them and may also have effects on unemployment